# macOS High Sierra Installation Fail

Tags: install, high-sierra

I wanted to install High Sierra and made a USB Installation Disk with [Disk Maker X](http://diskmakerx.com)

All goes well and the installation is doing fine.

Then this screen appears:

[image]

> OSX couldn't install on this computer. To enter the Apple Diagnostic program to test your hardware please hit `D` during reboot.

SO that's what I did.

Now holding `D` during reboot does exactly nothing but instead it goes to this screen:

[image]

And from this screen it then goes back to the former error.

And that's it. Nothing else is happening.

I can enter the Disk Utility when the error is appearing. But I can't Partition the HD nor delete it because *it is used by another process*.

Nice. Now what?

Comment: Precisely which Mac & what was the previous OS on it?

Comment: Can you get back into the macOS utilities boot menu at all anymore? ( Command (⌘)-R)

Comment: Mac mini Core i7" 2.3 (Late 2012). The Previous OS was El Capitan

Comment: I can enter the Boot Menu and choose the USB Stick with the ox Installation. But it still goes to the same screens from above. The Boot Menu has no effect at all.

Comment: Why are you using a Disk Maker X to create the USB flash drive installer? The macOS operating system already has the tools needed to create this USB flash drive installer. See the Apple website: [How to create a bootable installer for macOS](https://support.apple.com/de-de/HT201372).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

David Anderson was right. The Disk Maker X was the problem. The bootstick was corrupted apparently.

I created a boot Stick via [Terminal](https://support.apple.com/de-de/HT201372)

```
sudo /Applications/Install\ macOS\ High\ Sierra.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume /Volumes/MyVolume
```

The last time I did this a Bootable Stick wasn't as easy as one terminal command that's why I used this 3d party tool. Better keep away.

Thanks for the hint.